# header section of antlr cpp target does not allow extern functions with default arguments

Tags: c++, antlr4

C++ (g++ 5.4.0) has a strange restriction. The 2nd line is allowed, but the 4th line is not allowed:

```
extern yy(int x);
extern yy(int x);  // re-declaration of an extern function is allowed
extern xx(int x, int y=3);
extern xx(int x, int y=3); // but re-declaration of an an extern function with default args is not allowed
```

(This error can be converted to a warning using -fpermissive, but that also bypasses other errors, so it is not a good practice to use that compiler flag. So I do not use this flag.)

This problem manifests in antlr's cpp target code in the header section. The following header code:

```
// G.g4:
grammar G;
@parser::header {
extern xx(int x, int y=3);
}
```

gets generated as:

```
// GParser.h:
extern xx(int x, int y=3);
...

// GParser.cpp:
extern xx(int x, int y=3);
#include "GParser.h"
...
```

I am bypassing this error now, by re-coding like this:

```
// G.g4:
@parser::header {
#include "GHeader.h"
}

// GHeader.h:
#ifndef GHEADER
#define GHEADER
extern xx(int x, int y=3);
#endif //GHEADER
```

But is there a better way to do this in antlr4 itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary to put this code in the @header action? If not there are [other named actions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/cpp-target.md#named-actions) you could use. For instance `@parser::definitions` content goes to `.cpp` only. But this is a named action which is only available in the C++ target.

Comment: That was precisely my question, whether I am doing the right thing by putting my code in the header section. Thanks, I will check the other sections and decide which to use.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a restriction in GCC, that's a C++ restriction.

From [this default argument reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments):

> A redeclaration cannot introduce a default for an argument for which a default is already visible (even if the value is the same).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the pointer to language spec. But just curious, why this restriction for defaults only?